@JoinTable twice with different conditions
This question applies to a Java 17 web application running spring boot 3.2.4 and a postgres database.
I have the following schema, two entities related through a join table:

The project_contact.type field can have one of two values:
'primary'
'secondary'
An example of actual data might look like this:

For each instance of the project entity class, I need it to have a primary contact property and a secondary contact property.  I'm trying to accomplish this by creating two @ManyToOne relationships with the the contact entity, each one having a different @SQLJoinTableRestriction.
project.java
import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLJoinTableRestriction;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity(name = "project")
@Table(name = "project")
public class project {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    private long projectId;

    @Column(name = "project_name")
    private String projectName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(
        name = "project_contact",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "project_id",
            referencedColumnName = "project_id"
        ),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "contact_id",
            referencedColumnName = "contact_id"
        )
    )
    @SQLJoinTableRestriction("type = 'primary'")
    public contact primaryContact;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(
        name = "project_contact",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "project_id",
            referencedColumnName = "project_id"
        ),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "contact_id",
            referencedColumnName = "contact_id"
        )
    )
    @SQLJoinTableRestriction("type = 'secondary'")
    public contact secondaryContact;
}

contact.java
import java.util.List;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity(name = "contact")
@Table(name = "contact")
public class contact {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "contact_id")
    private long contactId;

    @Column(name = "contact_first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "contact_last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "project_contact",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "contact_id",
            referencedColumnName = "contact_id"
        ),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "project_id",
            referencedColumnName = "project_id"
        )
    )
    public List<project> projects;
}

When I run the app I'm getting this error:
ERROR Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Table with that name [project_contact] already associated with entity
If I remove the secondaryContact property along with its @ManyToOne and @JoinTable attributing the app builds and runs without errors.
If you can't have two joins on the same entity with different SQL filters, what is the correct way to achieve this?

project_contact is not a typical join table as it contains additional field. Consider it as an ordinary table among the others. This SQL query should do required work
select project.project_id, contact.contact_id, type
from project 
join project_contact on (project_contact.project_id = project.project_id)
join contact on (project_contact.contact_id = contact.contact_id);

This select statement may be considered as a view definition. Introduce new entity with required fields according to the view:
@Entity
@Immutable
@Subselect(
"select project.project_id, contact.contact_id, type "+
"from project "+"
"join project_contact on (project_contact.project_id = project.project_id) "+"
"join contact on (project_contact.contact_id = contact.contact_id)"
)
public class TypeView {

    // define embeddable key instead this three fields
    Long projectId;
    Long contactId;
    String type

}

About Subselect annotation please see tutorial at https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-subselect
